# akka websocket with java, counting clients number, sending message to client

Tags: java, concurrency, websocket, akka

I'm following the akka java websocket tutorial in attempt to create a websocket server. I want to implement 2 extra features:

- Being able to display the number of connected clients, but the result
  is always 0 or 1 , even when I know I have 100's concurrently
  connected clients.
- Websocket communication is biDirectional. Currently the server only respond with a message when client sends a message. How do I initiate sending a message from server to client?

Here's original akka java server example code with minimum modification of my client counting implementation:

```
public class websocketServer {
private static AtomicInteger connections = new AtomicInteger(0);//connected clients count.

public static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
//called every second to display number of connected clients.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Conncurrent connections: " + connections);
    }
}


//#websocket-handling
  public static HttpResponse handleRequest(HttpRequest request) {
      HttpResponse result;
      connections.incrementAndGet();
      if (request.getUri().path().equals("/greeter")) {
          final Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> greeterFlow = greeter();
          result = WebSocket.handleWebSocketRequestWith(request, greeterFlow);
      } else {
          result = HttpResponse.create().withStatus(413); 
      }
      connections.decrementAndGet();
      return result;
  }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
    TimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    try {
      final Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

      final Function<HttpRequest, HttpResponse> handler = request -> handleRequest(request);
      CompletionStage<ServerBinding> serverBindingFuture =
        Http.get(system).bindAndHandleSync(
          handler, ConnectHttp.toHost("****", 1183), materializer);


      // will throw if binding fails
      serverBindingFuture.toCompletableFuture().get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      System.out.println("Press ENTER to stop.");
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
      timer.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      system.terminate();
    }
  }

  //#websocket-handler

  /**
   * A handler that treats incoming messages as a name,
   * and responds with a greeting to that name
   */
  public static Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> greeter() {
    return
      Flow.<Message>create()
        .collect(new JavaPartialFunction<Message, Message>() {
              @Override
              public Message apply(Message msg, boolean isCheck) throws Exception {
                if (isCheck) {
                    if (msg.isText()) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        throw noMatch();
                    }
                } else {
                    return handleTextMessage(msg.asTextMessage());
                }
              }
        });
  }

  public static TextMessage handleTextMessage(TextMessage msg) {
    if (msg.isStrict()) // optimization that directly creates a simple response...
    {
        return TextMessage.create("Hello " + msg.getStrictText());
    } else // ... this would suffice to handle all text messages in a streaming fashion
    {
        return TextMessage.create(Source.single("Hello ").concat(msg.getStreamedText()));
    }
  }
  //#websocket-handler
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing your 2 bullet points below:

1 - you need to attach your metrics to the Message flow - and not to the HttpRequest flow - to effectively count the active connections. You can do this by using `watchTermination`. Code example for the handleRequest method below

```
public static HttpResponse handleRequest(HttpRequest request) {
  HttpResponse result;
  if (request.getUri().path().equals("/greeter")) {
    final Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> greeterFlow = greeter().watchTermination((nu, cd) -> {
      connections.incrementAndGet();
      cd.whenComplete((done, throwable) -> connections.decrementAndGet());
      return nu;
    });
    result = WebSocket.handleWebSocketRequestWith(request, greeterFlow);
  } else {
    result = HttpResponse.create().withStatus(413);
  }
  return result;
}
```

2 - for the server to independently send messages you could create its Message Flow using `Flow.fromSinkAndSource`. Example below (this will only send one message):

```
public static Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> greeter() {
  return Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore(),
    Source.single(new akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage.Strict("Hello!"))
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the watchTermination() answer, client counter is working correctly now. However for the server sending message independently, it's still relying on client sending some sort of message first before replying (communication happening once). Is there no way to keep a record of currently websocket-connected client and send the message when sever has some new info to deliver to the client?  something along the lines of 
clients.getClient("3353").send(new akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage.Strict("Hello!");

Answer (score 0):

In the `handleRequest` method you increment and then decrement the counter `connections`, so at the end the value is always 0.

```
public static HttpResponse handleRequest(HttpRequest request) {
      ...
      connections.incrementAndGet();
      ...
      connections.decrementAndGet();
      return result;
  }
```